# Java swing - displaying multiple images dynamically on JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

I have searched many places to add and display images dynamically on JPanel but couldn't get proper help.
Basically I have JPanel on which I have to display many images vertically but it should be dynamic.

```
for(int i=0;i<macthedImages.length;i++) {
    JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(macthedImages[i]));
    searchResultPanel.add(jLabel);
}
```

macthedImages is an array of bufferedImages
searchResultPanel is JPanel

Comment: Can't see image after execution

Comment: Are you sure the images are actually in your array?

Comment: yes they are...even i tried to display text in label ..but i dint work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show all images at same time then use GridLayout but you have to consider rows and columns of grid layout.

```
GridLayout gl = new gridLayout(2,macthedImages.length/2);
```

Or if you want to show one image at a time then use CardLayout. Like this:

```
CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
for(int i=0;i<macthedImages.length;i++){
        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(macthedImages[i]));
        cl.add(jLabel, "jLabel"+i);
    }
```

In second option you can show any image by firing event. It provides many [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html)

Comment: It works. I have used. write this code.
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(2,5);
jp.setLayout(gl);

Comment: Abhishek thanks for help but i did the same couldn't get any image there

Comment: Then problem is related to your code. Proper way to use gridlayout is this. If you are more confused i can show you complete working code.(If you required)

Comment: once i set layout to grid than i should add label to panel right?

Comment: Yes. After setting layout label should b added.

Answer (score 2):

1) you have to set proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html),

2) for lots of Images in the JLabel would be [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) best options, in case that you want to see all images on one JPanel

3) use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), if you want to see each Image separatelly

4) maybe there no needed re-create

```
JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(macthedImages[i]));
```

only to set

```
jLabel[i].setIcon(macthedImages[i]);
```

5) maybe put JPanel to the [JSCrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

6) if you add/remove JCOmponents on Runtime you have to call

```
revalidate();
repaint()// sometimes required
```