# How to display images using GridLayout on JPanel?

Tags: java, image, jpanel, grid-layout, japplet

What would be the most appropriate way to display 4 images using a `GridLayout(2,2)` on a `JPanel`?

Problem solved!! This is how I did it. It may not be efficient, but it's easy to read and it works :)
Feel free to let me know how this can be improved! I'm always looking for ways to improve how I code!

```
//      Create panel and set layout
        pFlag= new JPanel();
        pFlag.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,10,10)); 

//      Get image       
        flag1Img = getImage(getCodeBase(), "croatia.png");
        flag2Img = getImage(getCodeBase(), "eng.png");
        flag3Img = getImage(getCodeBase(), "romania.png");
        flag4Img = getImage(getCodeBase(), "spain.png");        

//      Set as icon     
        flag1Icon = new ImageIcon(flag1Img);
        flag2Icon = new ImageIcon(flag2Img);
        flag3Icon = new ImageIcon(flag3Img);
        flag4Icon = new ImageIcon(flag4Img);

//      Create JLabel       
        flag1Label = new JLabel();
        flag2Label = new JLabel();
        flag3Label = new JLabel();
        flag4Label = new JLabel();

//      Set JLabel alignment        
        flag1Label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        flag1Label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        flag2Label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        flag2Label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        flag3Label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        flag3Label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        flag4Label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        flag4Label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);     

//      Set JLabels as icons
        flag1Label.setIcon(flag1Icon);
        flag2Label.setIcon(flag2Icon);
        flag3Label.setIcon(flag3Icon);
        flag4Label.setIcon(flag4Icon);

//      Assign icons to images
        pFlag.add(flag1Label);
        pFlag.add(flag2Label);
        pFlag.add(flag3Label);
        pFlag.add(flag4Label);

        con.add(pFlag);
```

Comment: Trying to find the *most appropriate* duplicate...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java swing - displaying multiple images dynamically on JPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500746/java-swing-displaying-multiple-images-dynamically-on-jpanel)

Comment: *"..from a local folder"* Local to what? The server, or the client machine? Note that either way it is a directory, not a 'folder' - which is an entirely GUI concept. Which part are you having trouble with? What have you tried?

Comment: Oh in that case, slash the whole "local folder" thing. I'm only trying to make a JApplet. 
I've tried this but this but it only shows up as an empty panel. I haven't even gotten a single image to show up.

pFlag = new JPanel();
  pFlag.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,10,20)); 
  
  flag = getImage(getCodeBase(), "croatia.gif");

  con.add(pFlag);

Comment: `getCodeBase(),` where this points to will depend on the code base set in the HTML. Whether it can locate the image (it fails silently) depends on the structure of the server in terms of the location of the HTML, the class, and the image (show us the structure of the server, with the locations of those 3 things). And a tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson thanks a lot! I was trying to work with a different example that actually had html files whereas mine doesn't have any. I'll try what Keqiang Li suggested down there. And thanks for the tip too! Hahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your images into `JLabel`s.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
frame.setContentPane(panel);

frame.setVisible(true);
JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
panel.add(label1);
JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
panel.add(label2);
JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
panel.add(label3);
JLabel label4 = new JLabel();
panel.add(label4);

try {
    BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("test.jpg"));

    label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
    label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
    label3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
    label4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

frame.pack();
frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
```

**UPDATE** updated as Andrew Thompson suggested

This is a very simple Applet displays 4 images from an URL.

```
public class Main extends JApplet {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        add(panel);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        panel.add(label1);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
        panel.add(label2);
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
        panel.add(label3);
        JLabel label4 = new JLabel();
        panel.add(label4);

        try {
            URL url = new URL("YOU_IMAGE_URL.jpg");
            Image myPicture = getImage(url);

            label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
            label3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
            label4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));` Don't guess sizes. `pack()` the frame, then use its size as the basis for minimum size.

Comment: `new File("test.jpg")` This won't work in an applet, since it will be searching the local file system (of the client machine) for a file that does not exist!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you for pointing these out. Changed how the size was set. I thought she was only asking for how to put images into a `JPanel` using `GridLayout`. I have no idea where she wants to get the images.

Comment: @Keqiang Li Thanks! Sorry for the vagueness. I'm a total noob to stack and to Java. I'll this now!

Comment: @Keqiang Li 

It still doesn't work. I'm getting this error message :\

javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at EuroTicketLayout.init(EuroTicketLayout.java:204)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: @AbigailLo Read in your own images instead of mine. If that's not the case, can you show me more code?

Comment: BTW - I forgot to add that was a bloody tremendous idea to use `ImageIO` to load the image(s). It provides a heapin' helpin' of feedback (i.e. the stack trace) if something goes wrong - as opposed to the applet method to `getImage(..)` which will fail silently if the image is not found. If you could tweak your answer to use an URL for the image, I'd have no choice but to give it an 'up vote'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Just updated the answer to use the getImage() method and it worked well.  Thank you!

Comment: @AbigailLo Now I'm using an URL to load the image and I pasted the whole Main class for your convenience.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I actually solved it last night but only saw this today, but I will accept your answer nonetheless! I clicked the check icon. It doesn't stay green. I hope that still means i've accepted it? @Kequiang Li

Comment: @Kequiang Li I'll also post how I did it. I'll try what you did too to see what's more efficient! I feel as though I have waaaaaaay too much code

Comment: @AbigailLo You're welcome! I also learnt some thing from answering the question!